# InvalidTokenException: Unauthorized-401

Tags: oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am converting a application to use IPP .net API V3. I have already built all the OAuth and saved the token info.  Trying to make connection but always get error.  I have checked and recheck all the token data and it appears correct.  Where did I go wrong? I am using the DevDefined for OAuth and Intuit.Ipp from NuGet (IPP API V3). I am using my test customer token info but noticed the base URL (from the IPP library) is https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/.  Should that still work?

```
        Dim accessToken As String = QBOE.GetOAuthItem(Profile.Common.StoreNum, "accessToken")
    Dim accessTokenSecret As String = QBOE.GetOAuthItem(Profile.Common.StoreNum, "accessTokenSecret")
    Dim consumerKey As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("consumerKey")
    Dim consumerSecret As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("consumerSecret")
    Dim oauthValidator As OAuthRequestValidator = New OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret)

    Dim CompanyID As String = QBOE.GetOAuthItem(Profile.Common.StoreNum, "CompanyID")
    Dim appToken As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("applicationToken")
    Dim context As ServiceContext = New ServiceContext(appToken, CompanyID, IntuitServicesType.QBO, oauthValidator)

    Dim service As DataService = New DataService(context)

    Dim customer As Customer = New Customer()
    'Mandatory Fields
    customer.GivenName = "Mary"
    customer.Title = "Ms."
    customer.MiddleName = "Jayne"
    customer.FamilyName = "Cooper"

    Dim resultCustomer As Customer = TryCast(service.Add(customer), Customer)
```

Error Message (errors on service.Add)
    Intuit.Ipp.Exception.InvalidTokenException was unhandled by user code

I checked the calls within fiddler2 and noticed the calls for my OAuth is going through workplace.intuit.com:443 but the IPP calls go through quickbooks.api.intuit.com:443. I also noticed fiddler2 list the IPP call with a Result of 200.  Output shown below.

HeaderText:
CONNECT quickbooks.api.intuit.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: quickbooks.api.intuit.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

The data sent represents an SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake. For your convenience, the data is extracted below.

Major Version: 3
Minor Version: 1
Random: 53 2E 7C 6E A1 F4 02 4D 9D CF 60 C8 22 CA BC E8 67 6E D8 52 88 54 6F E7 D9 29 52 58 5C 2F 2E 52 
SessionID: 9E 01 CB DB D6 C8 78 8D D0 E9 A6 5F 02 1E 2C 6D 5D 69 34 FE FD 3E A5 52 EE 19 07 E7 D9 D6 E5 30 
Ciphers: 
    [002F] TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [0035] TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [0005] SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [000A] SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [C013] TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014] TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009] TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C00A] TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0032] TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [0038] TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0013] SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0004] SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

Reply Text:
HTTP/1.1 200 Blind-Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 01:17:18.298
EndTime: 01:17:18.536

This is a CONNECT tunnel, through which encrypted HTTPS traffic flows. To view the encrypted sessions inside this tunnel, ensure that the Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS > Decrypt HTTPS traffic option is checked.

The data sent represents an SSLv3-compatible ServerHello handshake. For your convenience, the data is extracted below.

Major Version: 3
Minor Version: 1
SessionID: 9E 01 CB DB D6 C8 78 8D D0 E9 A6 5F 02 1E 2C 6D 5D 69 34 FE FD 3E A5 52 EE 19 07 E7 D9 D6 E5 30 
Random: 63 E2 D0 B1 09 45 E0 28 A4 3B 0B C2 E8 5F 08 F0 D5 F5 8E A7 47 D4 10 E2 D4 D7 5B C4 74 0B 4B E2 
Cipher: 0x05

Answer (score 1):

You can try this call as mentioned in the following docs using IPP provided .net devkit.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

401 clearly signifies that your OAuth tokens/request header is not correct. 
To debug this, you can use any standard RestClients ( like RestClient plugins of Mozilla browser or Fiddler) where you can set four OAuth tokens [ consumer key, consumer Secret, access Key and access token) and content-type [application/xml]

- URI: https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company//customer
- Method: POST
- Content-Type: application/xml

Mozilla RestClient -

**Set OAuth Tokens**

[image]

**Set Content-type** ( in header )

[image]

[image]
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer

If the above approach works, that means your OAuth tokens are fine. You need to check and properly construct the header using devdefined then.

If it doesn't work then you need to generate a new set of access Token and Secret using IPP OAuth Playground.

https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.   That is the document (the one you linked, I build this from)   I have installed the RestClient addin for firefox already so will try your suggestion. I also updated the post with some findings from Fiddler (please see if that impacts your suggestion).   I am getting valid replies from all my OAuth calls and saving them off.   I also have cleared and reset (both with my programs OAuth process and within the Intuit playground) a number of times

Comment: " I am getting valid replies from all my OAuth calls and saving them off. " - does that mean everything in place now ? Mozilla RestClient works pretty well here.. Please let me know how it goes

Comment: No, just the OAuth side (where I do the call backs to set up new auth).  One items I don't understand is...  if I understand the IPP SDK it handles a lot of things for me (like the oauth_signature in the header).  How can I get that for my RestClient test call using the firefox addin?

Comment: I've added 3 snapshot. Plz have a look. Thanks

Comment: I went back and followed your directions at the start and walked through the playground setup.  It created different customerkey and consumerSecret than what is shown on the My Apps -> Manage App screen (still didn't change them there).  Anyway, I changed them in my web.config and now everything works.  Guessing somehow the customerKey and Secret got changed but never updates on the screen.  Thanks for your help, I have been fighting this for three days but at least I learned a lot.

Comment: Gr8. you've made it work. If possible, please mark this post as ans. Thanks