# What's the correct uri for QBO v3 API update operation?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to use the QBO v3 API object update function described [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/010_calling_data_services/040_update#Sparse_Updating). The [API explorer](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO) shows a different uri.

I'm trying to update an account with Id 42. Both of the following URIs get me a 401:

As the documentation would suggest:

https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/0123456789/account?requestid=42

(the above at least gives me a json blob with the 401)

As the api explorer would suggest:

https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/0123456789/account?operation=update

(here I don't even get the json, just a plain 401)

My request body is successful when I use the api explorer, so I don't believe that's the problem. I also don't believe authentication is the problem, because I can successfully create objects and also make queries with the same headers.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the Account object's ID into the URL. The [?requestid=] from [the documentation you mentioned](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/010_calling_data_services/040_update) apparently refers to an id related to the request (not the object in question). The API Explorer's URI appears to simply mislead (although I could certainly be missing something here).

In your example, just use this:

https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/0123456789/account

Let the headers and request body do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Correct BASE URI: https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/

you can refer example request/response section of any entity doc.

- Ref -https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/bill

To debug(401 authentication issue), you can use any standard RestClient.
In the following thread, I've explained how to use RestClinet plugin of Mozilla to test any QBO V3 endpoint.

- [InvalidTokenException: Unauthorized-401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587647/invalidtokenexception-unauthorized-401)

You can download IPP's devkit and using that devkit you can call any endpoints easily.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

Hope it will be useful.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Manas. I believe the Bill documentation led me to the solution. The general update operation documentation and the api explorer both kind of imply a different uri, so this was a helpful clarification. I appreciate how quickly you responded.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. If possible, please mark this as ans.
Thanks