# Add vendors in quickbooks from my salesforce application?

Tags: salesforce, quickbooks, apex

From my salesforce application, I need to connect to quickbook api and create vendors by a batch job.

For this Do I need to add whole Oauth process (add 'Connect to quickbooks' button and there will be a auth page, which when successfull will redirect me to the application).

Or there are other ways in which I can do this.

Can I use connection ticket. If yes, the how ?

Reall stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at IPP's docs. - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi

The only way to make a call to QBO endpoints is through 3-legged OAuth (using consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessKey and accessSecret). If you have desktop application then you need to have a web component/embedded browser for the first time users. Once you have the end-user tokens, you can store and reuse those for all future API calls.

If you create an app in appcenter, you'll get consumerKey and consumerSecret.
https://developer.intuit.com/Application/Create/IA

Using the above two tokens, you can generate accessToken and accessSecret using the OAuthPlayground.
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA

Devkit Download link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits
You need to plugin the above 4 tokens with java devkit code to make any QBO V3 REST call.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0/0001_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

**Re - Can I use connection ticket. If yes, the how ?**

No, OAuth is the only process here.

**Vendor** API doc - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/vendor

Hope it will be useful.

Thanks

Comment: which of these 4 fields (consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessKey and accessSecret) are company dependent ? Because I need to create vendors for many different companies from my batch job.

P.S. : don't worry i will accept this answer after 1-2 small queries.

Comment: AccessKey and accessSecret are company dependent. ConsumerKey, consumerSecret are static( get generated when you create an app in appcenter ).

Comment: I read in the docs that access token will get expire after 180 days. So access token generated by https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA will also get expired after 180 days ?

Comment: One more small ques, I am connected to quickbooks using this https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA , I can see blue dot. But where can i find accessToken and accessSecret ?
Do they come as a response to this request ?

Comment: In OAuthPlayground, you can set expiry duration. Bydefault it is 180 days. You can either renew tokens( in the time period 150 days to 179 days ) or you can go through Oauth flow again to generate new set of tokens.

After completing C2QB(OAuth) flow, please use 'App Menu API Test.' option which will show you accessToken and accessSecret. Thanks

Comment: I tried to make a http post request https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/companyId/entityName/entityId[?requestid=value]
 as mentioned in https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/010_calling_data_services/00100_requests_and_responses/0010_requests . and on header added all 4 fields (consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessKey and accessSecret) and i am getting **message=Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200** but when i make request with java quickbook library with same tokens, it gives me result. Any idea why?

Comment: Please check if you're using the correct content type. You can try this from any RESTClient as well. Please refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587647/invalidtokenexception-unauthorized-401

Comment: I used correct content type and i am using even same rest client. Still I am getting 401. But same tokens are working fine when used with data service api, i am getting requested results. That means tokens are fine. Any idea where I might be wrong. Why is it not working on rest client. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've seen issues with Mozilla's RESTClient plugin. You can try some other client and see if you are facing the same issue. Otherwise, you can raise a support ticket from IPP's docs site and share your OAuth token( if it is a dev tokens).

Comment: I tried it on chrome postman plugin, it threw **message=No apptoken detected; errorCode=003102; statusCode=401**, where should i define apptoken?

Comment: can you share the relamId ?

Comment: 379910056
Mine url is https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/379910056/vendor/2
I also created a separate question for this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025085/response-is-unauthorize-401-while-connecting-to-quickbook-api-when-tokens-are-va

Comment: please check if you are using GET instead of POST. Error log suggests - '/qbo27/v3/company/379910056/vendor/2 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR:No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header'. Thanks

Comment: i tried with both get and post. same getting 401. dude please help, i am struggling with this rest request for so many days, no progress at all.

Comment: Please raise a support ticket using this link - https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incidents
Please share your OAuth tokens(if those are of dev env). Thanks

Comment: If you can please provide me your email address, i will send you my oauth tokens privately.

Comment: All that i need to know is if I have these 4 tokens (consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessKey and accessSecret) and RelamId(QBO account), how to make a rest request in java/apex to quickbook api using any rest client / library (not devkit). I have tried these tokens with devkit and they worked. I need these to work with rest client.

Comment: Will an example with HttpClient and SignPost will help you ? As you know, both libs are open source.

Comment: Don't worry, I was able to use signpost and httpclient to make this rest request. Thanks.

Comment: Great.. But still I would try to share the code for others who have similar requirement.