# How to Sign a Request to the Quickbooks v3 Rest API

Tags: rest, oauth, quickbooks

I am attempting to build a signed request to reach the Quickbooks Online REST API. I can't use any of the available Libraries. I need to construct the signature and make the request by hand I am using what amounts to curl to make the requests

I have retrieved the all the tokens using the oAuth playground.

https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/

I couldn't find any discussion of how to sign the request specific for Quickbooks, but I did find a nice tutorial from Twitter on how to create a signature. I am assuming that quickbooks is following the oAuth1.0 spec like twitter. Perhaps I am wrong?

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature

Following the instructions there, I generated a signature using HMAC-SHA1 with hex encoding. I then constructed the Authorization header. This is what it looks like.

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="qyprdYK7bz25GNotXMtEhApqoBGv1P",
oauth_nonce="A77E0D5AB6FE4E369E2C30F4B1D3113D",
oauth_signature="REEzODg0NjM2Q0QwNkU3MjAyMTRBNjU0RjQ5OUFGNUM1RTQzQTgyOA==",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1410190307",
oauth_token="qyprdiNGZIHAj8VPN87ZhfOZ9mQJmVSCx98l2OBET9cYDL0b",
oauth_version="1.0"
```

However, I get an unauthorized response.

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-09-08T22:31:49.649Z" requestId="66cbe3bda8b1469ba3342b84ffea149d">
    <Fault type="AUTHENTICATION">
        <Error code="3102">
            <Message>message=No apptoken detected; errorCode=003102; statusCode=401</Message>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Is there something different about the Quickbooks REST v3 API use of oAuth? Are there any resources that describe how to sign a request for quickbooks?

..

Answer (score 0):

Intuit uses standard, vanilla OAuth for authentication.

You can refer to the spec for details on how to sign the request:

- http://oauth.net/

Are you *positive* that your consumer key and consumer secret are correct? It is highly unlikely that you have them correct.

Answer (score 0):

For Java -(using signPost) [How to call API (Oauth 1.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418764/how-to-call-api-oauth-1-0)

SignPost lib is opensource. If you don't want to use the lib(as you've mentioned), then you can have a look at the lib's sourcecode.

C# -(using devdefined) https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/0913b4c224de758fde0a

Otherwise, you can try these API call from any standard REST client. You can compare the header generated from that client with the same which you're manually constructing.

Please refer the following post to see how to call QB V3 endpoint using Fiddler.

- [Fiddler example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025085/response-is-unauthorize-401-while-connecting-to-quickbook-api-when-tokens-are-va)
- [Mozilla RESTClient example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587647/invalidtokenexception-unauthorized-401)

Hope it will be useful.

Thanks