# Quickbooks authentication error - Java SDK Quickbooks v3.0

Tags: java, web-services, rest, quickbooks

This is my first attempt to work with [Quickbooks](http://quickbooks.intuit.com/) API. To get started with it I wanted to try few API calls.

I have already created account on Quickbooks and got the following credentials -

```
consumerKey
consumerSecret
accessToken
accessTokenSecret
appToken
companyId
```

Downloaded [IPP java sdk for QuickBooks v3.0](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0) and the from the downloaded package, I am currently using the following jar files -

```
ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
ipp-java-qbapihelper-1.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Here is the code which I am executing.

```
import com.intuit.ipp.core.Context;
import com.intuit.ipp.core.ServiceType;
import com.intuit.ipp.data.Customer;
import com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException;
import com.intuit.ipp.security.OAuthAuthorizer;
import com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService;

 public class TestQuickBooks {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws FMSException 
   {
    // following credentials are replaced with my original credential
    // when executing the code 
    String consumerKey = "...";
    String consumerSecret = "...";
    String accessToken = "...";
    String accessTokenSecret = "...";
    String appToken = "...";
    String companyId = "...";

    try {
      OAuthAuthorizer oauth = new OAuthAuthorizer(consumerKey,
                                                  consumerSecret,
                                                  accessToken,
                                                  accessTokenSecret);
      Context context = new Context(oauth,
                                    appToken,
                                    ServiceType.QBO,
                                    companyId);
      DataService service = new DataService(context);

      Customer customer1 = new Customer();
      customer1.setDisplayName("ABCD");

      // this is the line which is throwing exception
      Customer resultCustomer = service.add(customer1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

copying the exception message here --

```
com.intuit.ipp.exception.AuthenticationException: ERROR CODE:3200, ERROR MESSAGE:message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401, ERROR DETAIL:null
```

I am checking Quickbooks documentation but can't figure out what is causing this authentication exception. As for the credentials, I have double checked it and those are correct.

I found that Quickbooks has an [API playground](https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/API) but no luck with this as well.

Tried this API call -

```
https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/PingSecure
```

I provided my credentials and specified format as JSON and no url parameter.
it is returning the following message -

```
{
    "ErrorMessage": "This API requires Authorization.",
    "ErrorCode": 22,
    "ServerTime": "/Date(1412166272838)/"
}
```

My hope was api playground shouldn't return authentication error since my credentials were correct. However the only way I can see api calls is when I log in to the [API explorer](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer)

I am not really sure what is missing here - can't make an API call from API playground and also programmatically using Java SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Please add the below property:

```
Config.setProperty(Config.BASE_URL_QBO,"https://sandboxquickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company");
```

before:

```
DataService service = new DataService(context);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Given URL is not working. I changed it to [https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company](https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

401 suggests 'authentication' error.

Please refer this post, where I've mentioned how to call QBO V3 endpoints, using any standard Restclient.

[InvalidTokenException: Unauthorized-401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587647/invalidtokenexception-unauthorized-401)

If you see a 401 exception again, then please generate a new set of accessToken and accessSecret using [OAuthPlayground](https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA) tool and use those in Java devkit.